# Help with check login

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Hey guys, I'm new to mysqli and I have a question. I just updated my login check to use mysqli and prepared statement, and everything seems ok. But you can never be too safe. So could you please tell me if something is wrong in this piece of code?

```
 <?php
       ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);



              $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost", "***", "***","***") ;
              if(!$mysqli){
                die("Database error");
                }


              function checklogin($username, $password){
                global $mysqli;


                $result = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? and password=?");
                $result->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
                $result->execute();

            if($result != false){

                $dbArray=$result->fetch();


                if(!$dbArray){
                    echo '<p class="statusmsg">The username or password you entered is incorrect, or you haven\'t yet activated your account. Please try again.</p><br/><input class="submitButton" type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                    return;
                }
                $_SESSION['username']=$username;

                if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
                    setcookie("jmuser",$username,time()+60*60*24*356);  
                    setcookie("jmpass",$password ,time()+60*60*24*356);
                }
                echo'<p class="statusmsg"> You have successfully logged in. You will now be redirected to the homepage.</p>';
            redirect();
            }

            else{
                echo'<p class="statusmsg">  The username or password you entered is incorrect. Please try again.</p><br/>input class="submitButton" type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";
                return;
            }
        }   

                if(isset($_COOKIE['jmuser']) && isset($_COOKIE['jmpass'])){

                $status=checkCookie($_COOKIE['jmuser'], $_COOKIE['jmpass']);
                if($status==true){
                    echo '<p class="statusmsg"> Welcome back '.$_COOKIE['jmuser'].'. You will now be redirected to the homepage.</p>';
                    sleep(5);
                    redirect();

                }
            }

       else{


        if(isset($_POST['sublogin'])){

        if(( strlen($_POST['user']) >0) && (strlen($_POST['pass']) >0)) {

            checklogin($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']);

        }
        elseif((isset($_POST['user']) && empty($_POST['user'])) || (isset($_POST['pass']) && empty($_POST['pass']))){

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You didn\'t fill in the required fields.</p><br/><input class="submitButton" type="button" value="Retry" onClick="location.href='."'login.php'\">";

        }
        }
        else{

            echo '<p class="statusmsg">You came here by mistake, didn\'t you?</p>';

        }   


        }
```

And also when the login works it doesn't seem to redirect me to index.php. Here is the code written just above the  tag.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url'])){

function redirect() {
    header('location:'.$_GET['url']);
}
}
else {
    function redirect() {
        header('location: index.php');
        }
        }

?>
```

I tried deleting the text to no avail. I think I know the problem. When the login button is being clicked I get this in the address bar: localhost/JMToday/loginchk.php?url= So url is blank and so it redirects nowhere. Unless my theory is wrong :P Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setcookie("jmuser",$username,time()+60*60*24*356);  
setcookie("jmpass",$password ,time()+60*60*24*356);
```

Do *NOT* store usernames/passwords in the clear in cookies. Instead, assign a hash value of some sort to the user which can be used as a key to their user record

Comment: why not? and how can I assign a hash value? Using md5($password) or something like that?

Comment: Putting that data into cookies is a security risk. Anyone with the most trivial of network sniffers (or even just some javascript in the browser) would be able to steal your users' login credentials. For the hash, you'd want something better than md5. A salted sha1() of username/password would be better. Store that in the user record, then use it as a key for subsequent visits. That'd make it impossible to get the user's username/password, though an attack could still get into your site if they stole this token.

Comment: So not only do I store the cookie as sha1() but also the actual signup details?

Comment: Well, storing passwords as plain text anywhere is considered bad form. But it boils down to how secure you want things to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect after outputting anything to the browser.  Well, not without output buffering, but then nothing would show up until the script was finished or output buffering was ended.  Header() writes to the headers sent at the beginning of the file requested, and it can't do that if anything has been sent except other headers.  If you want to redirect after something has been sent, you'll have to use an HTML meta refresh, or JavaScript.

Comment: I tried deleting the text to no avail. I think I know the problem. When the login button is being clicked I get this in the address bar: http://localhost/JMToday/loginchk.php?url= 
So url is blank and so it redirects nowhere. Unless my theory is wrong :P Could you please help?

Comment: Well, you'd probably have to change the form action to "localhost/JMToday/loginchk.php?url=whatever" rather than just ?url=, or, in the if structure to determine where to redirect to, do `if(isset($_GET['url']) && $_GET['url'] != "")` or `if(isset($_GET['url']) && file_exists($_GET['url']))`

Answer (score -1):

Typically i find it better, if you just try out some specific things, like SQL injection. If your stuff breaks by using a simple ' in either of the text fields, its pretty vulnerable to SQL injection (which is wont be, with your use of preparedstatements).

For simple purposes it seems like a great script :-)

As has been posted, your redirect will not function if you already have outputted text with print/echo or sent some other header thats going to interfere with a redirect header.

Comment: Nope, it is not vulnerable in his case

Comment: so it won't be, as he's using it. So, what's the point of your answer?

Comment: You say its vulnerable, when my answers purpose is to define how to check whether it is or not. I also write that it is not vulnerable, yet you seem to have a need to repeat what i wrote in a comment and vote my answer down.

Comment: Well it's either not a legitimate answer because it has too weak relation to the actual question asked, and also you provided no real information on how to check. So, it should be a comment, not answer. Just a by the way note.

Comment: if you check my reputation, you can see that i dont have enough rep to do this.